# PySpark Window Function Comprehension

Tags: python, function, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been using PySpark to run a large number of calculations in a fairly large RDD whose each block look like this:

```
ID  CHK  C1 Flag1   V1  V2  C2  Flag2   V3  V4  
341 10  100 TRUE    10  10  150 FALSE   10  14
341 9   100 TRUE    10  10  150 FALSE   10  14
341 8   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   10  14
341 7   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   10  14
341 6   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   10  14
341 5   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   10  14
341 4   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   12  14
341 3   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   14  14
341 2   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   14  14
341 1   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   14  14
341 0   100 TRUE    14  14  150 FALSE   14  14
```

I have many occurrences of the ID (it depends on C1 values, for instance from 100 to 130 and so on for many C1s, for each integer I have a set of 11 rows like the ones above) and I have many IDs. What I need to do is apply a formula in each rows' group and add two columns that will calculate:

```
D1 = ((row.V1 - prev_row.V1)/2)/((row.V2 + prev_row.V2)/2)
D2 = ((row.V3 - prev_row.V3)/2)/((row.V4 + prev_row.V4)/2)
```

What I did (as i found in this helpful article: https://arundhaj.com/blog/calculate-difference-with-previous-row-in-pyspark.html) is to define a window:

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy().orderBy(desc("CHK"))
```

and for each intermediate calculation I created a "temp" column:

```
df = df.withColumn("prev_V1", lag(df.V1).over(my_window))
df = df.withColumn("prev_V21", lag(df.TA1).over(my_window))
df = df.withColumn("prev_V3", lag(df.SSQ2).over(my_window))
df = df.withColumn("prev_V4", lag(df.TA2).over(my_window))
df = df.withColumn("Sub_V1", F.when(F.isnull(df.V1 - df.prev_V1), 0).otherwise((df.V1 - df.prev_V1)/2))
df = df.withColumn("Sub_V2", (df.V2 + df.prev_V2)/2)
df = df.withColumn("Sub_V3", F.when(F.isnull(df.V3 - df.prev_V3), 0).otherwise((df.V3 - df.prev_V3)/2))
df = df.withColumn("Sub_V4", (df.V4 + df.prev_V4)/2)
df = df.withColumn("D1", F.when(F.isnull(df.Sub_V1 / df.Sub_V2), 0).otherwise(df.Sub_V1 / df.Sub_V2))
df = df.withColumn("D2", F.when(F.isnull(df.Sub_V3 / df.Sub_V4), 0).otherwise(df.Sub_V3 / df.Sub_V4))
```

Lastly I got rid of the temp columns:

```
final_df = df.select(*columns_needed)
```

It took way to long and I kept getting:

```
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

I know that I am not doing this properly as the code block above is inside a couple of for loops in order to do the calculations for all IDs, i.e. looping using:

```
unique_IDs = list(df1.toPandas()['ID'].unique())
```

but after looking into more on PySpark Window functions I believe that by setting correctly the window partitionBy() I could get the same result way easier.

I had a look on [Avoid performance impact of a single partition mode in Spark window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions) but still I am not sure how I could set my window partition correctly to make this work.

Can someone provide me some help or insight on how I could tackle this?

Thank you

Comment: What I need to do is apply a formula in each rows' group -- you mean group of  ID and C1 ? If so, then your partition should be on those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that the formula has to be applied to each group of ID (that's the reason why I chose to partition on 'ID').

You could avoid using the 'temp' columns with something like this :

```
# used to define the lag of a specific column
w_lag=Window.partitionBy("id","C1").orderBy(desc('chk'))


df = df.withColumn('D1',((df.V1-F.lag(df.V1).over(w_lag))/2)\
                       /((df.V2+F.lag(df.V2).over(w_lag))/2))

df = df.withColumn('D2',((df.V3-F.lag(df.V3).over(w_lag))/2)\
                       /((df.V4+F.lag(df.V4).over(w_lag))/2))
```

The result is :

```
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
| id|chk| C1|Flag1| V1| V2| C2|Flag2| V3| V4|                 D1|                 D2|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
|341| 10|100| true| 10| 10|150| true| 10| 14|               null|               null|
|341|  9|100| true| 10| 10|150| true| 10| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  8|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 10| 14|0.16666666666666666|                0.0|
|341|  7|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 10| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  6|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 10| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  5|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 10| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  4|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 12| 14|                0.0|0.07142857142857142|
|341|  3|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 14| 14|                0.0|0.07142857142857142|
|341|  2|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 14| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  1|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 14| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
|341|  0|100| true| 14| 14|150| true| 14| 14|                0.0|                0.0|
+---+---+---+-----+---+---+---+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This seems close to what I had in mind, my only concern is whether this would work for the entire dataset as e.g. the next "data block" will also have id = 341 and chk = 10 -> 0 but the C1 would be 110. Do you think that doing  w_lag=Window.partitionBy("id","C1").orderBy(desc('chk')) would solve this?

Lastly I think you have something a bit off as when D1 = 0.16666 it should have been:  ((14-10)/2)/(14+14/2) = 2/14 = 0.1428

Comment: I just edited my answer. Indeed : Window.partitionBy("id","C1") should be better for what you want. As for D1 = 0.16666 : I think it is ((14-10)/2)/((14+10)/2)=2/12=0.1666

Comment: You are right, my bad! Thank you so much for the response!