# Retrieve specific row number data of a column in spark dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset as below

```
+---------+
| column1 |
+---------+
| ABC     |
+---------+
| DEF     |
+---------+
| GHI     |
+---------+
| JKL     |
+---------+
| MNO     |
+---------+
```

Now if have to get the  4th row column value that is `JKL`. Is there anyway to get that directly.
I normally do as below

```
String dataTemp = df.select("column1").collectAsList().get(3).getAs("column1").toString();
```

But I don't want to collect as list everytime, which can cause issues when dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only limited number of rows can be collected with "take", in Scala:

```
val fourthRow = df.select("column1").take(4).last
```

If selection number is big, switch to RDD is possible:

```
val fourthRow = df.rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(_._2 == 4).keys.collect().head
```

Comment: We cannot go by this approach when dataset is large and the number can change every time right it cannot be only 4

Answer (score 1):

Use `row_number` to assign each row an index and then select row with `rn = 4`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val row  = df.withColumn("rn", row_number().over(Window.orderBy(lit(1))))
             .filter("rn = 4")
             .select($"column1").first
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to me the only correct way you can achieve this without using collect().

Comment: Message is displayed for such approach: 
"No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation."
In question large dataset mentioned, maybe, such approach will lead to OOM.

Comment: @pasha701 check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions).

Comment: think this works but is no better than collecting the data, without partitioning, this will move data to 1 machine...