# Inverse a column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

```
 a   b 
'1'  1
'2'  2
'3'  3
'4'  4
```

I would like to insert a new column which is the inverse of the b column while keeping the other columns constant.
Example:

```
 a   b  c
'1'  1  4
'2'  2  3
'3'  3  2 
'4'  4  1
```

We use temp['b'][::-1] to achieve this result in pandas. Is this transformation possible in pyspark as well?

Comment: Do you know the range of column 'b'? Is it consecutive?

Comment: How do you define ordering in the dataframe? There's no concept of an index in a spark dataframe since the data is possibly distributed so you need to define an ordering criteria with orderby.

Comment: @NirHedvat 'b' column isn't consecutive. It can contain any numeric value.

Comment: @rchrome The dataframe is already ordered by the column 'a'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe is ordered by column `a`.

You could try performing a self-join on a generated column that reverses the order. Such a column, `rn`, could be generated using `row_number` eg

#### Using pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

output_df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "rn",
        F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a"))
    )
    .alias("df1")
    .join(
        df.withColumn(
            "rn",
            F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.col("a").desc()))
        ).alias("df2"),
        ["rn"],
        "inner"
    )
    .selectExpr("df1.a","df1.b","df2.b as c")
    
)
```

#### Using spark sql

```sql
    select
        df1.a,
        df1.b,
        df2.b as c
    from (
        select
            *,
            row_number() over (order by a) rn
        from 
            df
    ) df1
    INNER JOIN (
        select
            b,
            row_number() over (order by a desc) rn
        from 
            df
    ) df2 on df1.rn=df2.rn;
```

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2FoW73HeRLb4DvgXzrWuqH/0)

Comment: Don't window functions without partitioning result in all data being collected to a single node?

Comment: @HristoIliev There is a good response in response to the question in your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions)

Comment: So `F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a"))` may blow up the memory of some executor in the general case, if `df` is large enough? Or is there some distributed magic I'm missing here?