# Sum a column values based on a condition using spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe like this:

| JoiKey | period | Age | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jk1 | 2022-02 | 2 | 200 |
| Jk1 | 2022-02 | 3 | 450 |
| Jk2 | 2022-03 | 5 | 500 |
| Jk3 | 2022-03 | 0 | 200 |
| Jk2 | 2022-02 | 8 | 300 |
| Jk3 | 2022-03 | 9 | 200 |
| Jk2 | 2022-04 | 1 | 100 |

Is there any way using **spark scala** to create two new columns based on condition.

**Column Amount (Age <= 3) >> Sum of amount having age > 3** and
**Column Amount (Age > 3) >> Sum of amount having age <= 3**

**Need to group-by  by Joinkey and Period and drop column "Age" and "Amount"**

Desired Output will be :

| JoiKey | period | Amount (Age <= 3) | Amount (Age > 3) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jk1 | 2022-02 | 650 | 0 |
| Jk2 | 2022-03 | 0 | 500 |
| Jk2 | 2022-02 | 0 | 300 |
| Jk2 | 2022-04 | 100 | 0 |
| Jk3 | 2022-03 | 200 | 200 |

Comment: Can you please add an example output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, but how would you expect your data to be? If you expect your output to be something like:

```
Age   Amount    A    B
 2     200     500  1450
 3     450     500  1450
 5     500     500  1450
 0     200     500  1450
 8     300     500  1450
 9     200     500  1450
 1     100     500  1450
```

Then this is a windowed aggregate function (windowing over sum). A windowing function is used to place an aggregated value for all the rows (in this case).

```scala
df
  .withColumn(
    "A",
    sum(when(col("Age") lt 3, col("Amount")).otherwise(lit(0)))
  .over()
)
.withColumn(
    "B",
    sum(when(col("Age") >= 3, col("Amount")).otherwise(lit(0)))
  .over()
)
```

Note that using `over` window function without partitioning is not performant at all, use partitioning.
Here's the output:

```
22/04/25 23:54:01 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+---+------+---+----+
|Age|Amount|  A|   B|
+---+------+---+----+
|  2|   200|500|1450|
|  3|   450|500|1450|
|  5|   500|500|1450|
|  0|   200|500|1450|
|  8|   300|500|1450|
|  9|   200|500|1450|
|  1|   100|500|1450|
+---+------+---+----+
```

---

**Update:**
So after you updated the question, I suggest you to do this:

```scala
df
  .groupBy(
    col("JoinKey"), col("period"), expr("Age < 3").as("under3")
  ).agg(sum(col("Amount")) as "grouped_age_sum")
  .withColumn("A", sum(when(col("under3") === true, col("grouped_age_sum")).otherwise(lit(0)))
  .over()
  )
  .withColumn("B", sum(when(col("under3") === false, col("grouped_age_sum")).otherwise(lit(0)))
  .over()
  ).drop("grouped_age_sum", "under3")
  .groupBy(col("JoinKey"), col("period")).min()
  .withColumnRenamed("min(A)", "A")
  .withColumnRenamed("min(B)", "B")
  .show
```

Please note that the same thing about partitioning still exists, I had some few sample data and didn't really need performance (it would've also add some logic dependent boilerplate to the solution), but you should do it, here's the output:

```
22/04/26 22:36:48 WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
+-------+-------+---+----+
|JoinKey| period|  A|   B|
+-------+-------+---+----+
|    JK1|2022-02|500|1450|
|    JK2|2022-03|500|1450|
|    JK3|2022-03|500|1450|
|    JK2|2022-02|500|1450|
|    JK2|2022-04|500|1450|
+-------+-------+---+----+
```

**Update #2:**

After clearer explanations you provided: so you just need grouping with 2 simple aggregate functions:

```scala
df
    .groupBy(col("JoinKey"), col("period"))
    .agg(
      sum(when(col("Age") lt 4, col("Amount")).otherwise(lit(0))).as("Amount (Age <= 3)"),
      sum(when(col("Age") gt 3, col("Amount")).otherwise(lit(0))).as("Amount (Age > 3)")
    )
```

Output:

```
+-------+-------+-----------------+----------------+
|JoinKey| period|Amount (Age <= 3)|Amount (Age > 3)|
+-------+-------+-----------------+----------------+
|    JK1|2022-02|              650|               0|
|    JK2|2022-03|                0|             500|
|    JK3|2022-03|              200|             200|
|    JK2|2022-02|                0|             300|
|    JK2|2022-04|              100|               0|
+-------+-------+-----------------+----------------+
```

Comment: You can read learn about [spark partitioning on window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions)

Comment: thank you for this info. I am unable to understand the use of min() here. Can you pls explain.

Comment: @NaveenPandey, In this case, values of column “A” will always be 500 (same thing foes for column B). So we’ll use the minimum of [500, 500, 500, 500, 500] (which will be 500). It’s a common pattern when you want to use a value as a column