# Define partition for window operation using Pyspark.pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to learn how to use `pyspark.pandas` and I am coming across an issue that I don't know how to solve. I have a `df` of about 700k rows and 7 columns. Here is a sample of my data:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
import pandas as pd

data = {'Region': ['Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Africa','Asia','Asia','Asia'],
         'Country': ['South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','South Africa','Japan','Japan','Japan'],
         'Product': ['ABC','ABC','ABC','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','DEF','DEF','DEF'],
         'Year': [2016, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2018, 2019,2016, 2017, 2019],
         'Price': [500, 0,450,750,0,0,890,19,120,3],
         'Quantity': [1200,0,330,500,190,70,120,300,50,80],
         'Value': [600000,0,148500,350000,0,29100,106800,74300,5500,20750]}

df = ps.DataFrame(data)
```

Even when I run the simplest of operations like `df.head()`, I get the following warning and I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
WARN window.WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

I know how to work around this with `pyspark` dataframes, but I'm not sure how to fix it using the Pandas API for Pyspark to define a partition for window operation.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This might help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41313488/avoid-performance-impact-of-a-single-partition-mode-in-spark-window-functions)

Answer (score 0):

For Koalas, the repartition seems to only take in a number of partitions here: https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/api/databricks.koalas.DataFrame.spark.repartition.html

I think the goal here is to run Pandas functions on a Spark DataFrame. One option you can use is [Fugue](https://github.com/fugue-project/fugue). Fugue can take a Python function and apply it on Spark per partition. Example code below.

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Any
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({"date":["2021-01-01", "2021-01-02", "2021-01-03"] * 3,
                   "id": (["A"]*3 + ["B"]*3 + ["C"]*3),
                   "value": [3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 5, 3, 2, 3]})


def count(df: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # this assumes the data is already partitioned
    id = df.iloc[0]["id"]
    count = df.shape[0]
    return pd.DataFrame({"id": [id], "count": [count]})

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)

from fugue import transform

# Pandas
pdf = transform(df.copy(),
          count,
          schema="id:str, count:int",
          partition={"by": "id"})
print(pdf.head())

# Spark
transform(sdf,
          count,
          schema="id:str, count:int",
          partition={"by": "id"},
          engine=spark).show()
```

You just need to annotate your function with input and output types and then you can use it with the Fugue transform function. Schema is a requirement for Spark so you need to pass it. If you supply `spark` as the engine, then the execution will happen on Spark. Otherwise, it will run on Pandas by default.