# Pyspark performance improvement

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the following code in a PySpark df:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(col, F.rank()over(Window.orderBy((col))))
```

Since my df has 2k columns it is very time inefficient. How can I improve it so that it takes less time? Tried some UDFs but with no success.

Comment: when you have a moment would you be able to provide some code examples? not exactly sure what you mean right now

Comment: what are you even trying to achieve with such a code. You are replacing each column with its rank ordered by that column ?

Comment: yes, I am using this to run some stats on the dataset

Comment: the window is not using partitions, so the performance won't be too [good](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41313488/2129801) in any case

Answer (score 0):

Please note trying a window function without `partitionBy` clause will cause performance degradation on large data. Try to model the data such that there is some column on which you can apply a partition on.

Supposedly PySpark will throw this warning to indicate the issue:

```bash
WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.
```

However, as an alternative to the `for` loop you can use the `selectExpr` method which can have a single pass using and it also leverages the use of Catalyst optimizer as well to make it run faster.

```py
# Create a list of SQL expressions that apply the rank function to each column
exprs = [f"rank() OVER (ORDER BY {col}) as {col}" for col in df.columns]

# Apply all expressions at once using selectExpr
df = df.selectExpr(*exprs)
```

or

```py
# Create a list of expressions that apply the rank function to each column
exprs = [F.rank().over(Window.orderBy(col)).alias(col) for col in df.columns]

# Apply all expressions at once using selectExpr
df = df.select(*exprs)
```

Do see if there is a possibility to apply `PARTITION BY` or `partitionBy` on any column which can improve performance for large tables.

Comment: Wasnt able to succesfully run the 1st option, the 2nd option worked fine but I didn't notice an increase in performance unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't able to find an elegant solution I noticed that there was a significant performance drop the more column I was trying convert. Based on that I have just split my dataset to include only ~400 columns for conversion each time and than joined these tables back together at the end. Not exactly what I was hoping for but did the job.